# How Do I Get My Question Unmarked As Duplicate?

Tags: support, duplicates

I tend to use Stack Overflow rather than Ask Ubuntu so although my post count is low here I do have a good appreciation of the Stack Exchange sites and asking "good" questions.

My question [How Do I ReOrder The Nautilus Right-Click Menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491145/how-do-i-reorder-the-nautilus-right-click-menu) got marked as a duplicate when even a cursory reading of my question and the linked questions make it is clear that they are not.

As I commented, the [first suggested duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21953/how-do-i-customize-the-context-menu-in-nautilus) is about adding new items to the menu, [the second one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281062/how-to-get-nautilus-scripts-working-on-ubuntu-13-04) is about adding scripts to the menu. I asked about re-ordering the existing menu.

Those are quite clearly different questions.

How do I get my question unmarked as a duplicate?

Comment: Please read the help page on reopening a closed question http://askubuntu.com/help/reopen-questions

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Asking here on meta is one way, asking in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) is another. But the *best* way to get your question reopened is to edit it with an explanation of why it isn't a duplicate. Comments are good but edits will put your post in a queue of potential reopen candidates.

Another good option would be casting a flag. Use flag -> in need of moderator attention and explain why your question isn't a duplicate.